Using UnsafeMutablePointer<T> inside DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform (Xcode 16 RC1, Swift 6 Warning)
Xcode 16 RC 1 gives me (Swift 6) a warning Capture of pixelBuffer with non-sendable type UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA32> in a @Sendable closure; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode.
What to do to remove those warnings?
My function (one of many with same warning) (warning is for capturing pixelBuffer inside DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform):
private static func getPixelationPixels(
        inputCGImage: CGImage,
        pixelBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA32>
    ) -> [PixelationPixel] {
    let width = inputCGImage.width
    let height = inputCGImage.height
    let all = width * height
    var pixels = [PixelationPixel]()
    pixels.reserveCapacity(all)
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: height) { row in
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: width) { column in
            let offset = row * width + column
            // !!! Warning HERE !!! 
            let c = pixelBuffer[offset].convertToUIColor()
            locker.withLock {
                pixels.append(
                    PixelationPixel(
                        color: c,
                        offset: offset
                    ))
            }
        }
    }
    Helper.randomFifty {
        pixels.reverse()
    }
    return pixels
}

